# Am I on the hook for medical bills by people that are on my health insurance?

Tags: united-states, health-insurance

I provide insurance for my ex-wife. Let's says the insurance pays 80% of the cost and they bill her for the rest.

Am I liable for the remaining 20% if she doesn't pay?

P.S. This is not a question whether I should or should not provide her health insurance (I know the answer to that) - just whether I am liable.

Answer (score 1):

When a member of my family goes to a new doctor they fill out forms that lays out who is responsible for the medical bills for each patient. the form does ask for insurance information, but also who cover the co-payment, co-insurance, deductibles, and uncovered expenses. They also ask us to provide an annual update for this information.

The answer will be what you told the doctor when you contacted for those services. They will send a bill the the responsible party. If you don't want to be responsible for those expenses that won't be reimbursed by the insurance company you must notify the doctors office prior to the service being performed.

Comment: So this an opt-out scenario? It seems to me that she can't assign liability to her ex-husband, unless that was formally written in their divorce agreement. She can claim anyone is liable for her costs, in the event that the insurance doesn't pay up, but that doesn't make it true....